# Deal with enum bitwise size greater than 64

Tags: c, enums, bit-manipulation

my enum is like this:

```
enum my_enum
{
      first_val = (1LLU << 0),
      second_val = (1LLU << 1),
      ...
      last_val = first_val = (1LLU << 63)
};
```

but in this way I'm limited to use only 64 values, the question is how can I deal with more than 64 values in my case and in one enum?

Thank you.

Comment: How many more? 500 bits?

Comment: The maximum size of an enum is implementation defined so there is no general answer to this question.

Comment: vz0 - about another 64 values

Comment: Nothing forces you to use bit values. enum { v1 = 1, v2 = 2, v3 = 3, v4 = 4, ..., v100000 = 100000 }; works just fine.

Comment: Do the enum values have to be powers of 2? Why not just count sequentially?

Comment: @gnasher729- no, because I use them in another control like this: `if (ctrl & (first_val | third_val)) ... `

Comment: @Armageddon: Then surely your question is actually "what type should I be using for `ctrl`?"...

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth - no, because I use an array with 2 case of 32 bit size :)

Comment: `ctrl` is an array? You cannot use `&` on an array.

Comment: @mafso - I can if I make something like: `((ctrl[1] << 32) | ctrl[0]) & (first_val | third_val))`

Comment: You are mistaken, and your compiler should already have told you, even 64 bit doesn't work reliably with `enum`. The constants that you define with `enum` have type `int` in any conforming C implementation. Most commonly this is only 32 bit wide, and you have to deal with signed values if you really want to exploit all these 32 bits. Using values that are larger than `INT_MAX` has implementation defined behavior and is thus not portable.

Comment: @Armageddon So you use the elements of the enum as flags. Do you really need more than 64 flags ?

Comment: @Michael Walz - yes, I want a maximum of flags equal to 128

Comment: Why don't you use a struct with 128 bitfields?

Answer (score 3):

As per `C11  6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers /2` (my bold):

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that **has a value representable as an int.**

Hence the only way you can currently have an enumeration `N` bits wide is if your `int` type is `N` bits wide. You'd be hard pressed trying to find an implementation with better than 64-bit `int` values currently (though I don't doubt they're coming).

Enumerations are probably better suited for consecutive values rather than bit masks. If you want to do bit masks of arbitrary size, you should consider an array of unsigned integral types, preferably fixed size like `uint8_t`, to simplify your processing.

The following routines are probably a good start. First, the required headers, structure and helper array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t sz;
    uint8_t data[];
} tBitSet;

uint8_t bitMask[] = { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };
```

Next, the allocation and deallocation functions:

```
tBitSet *bitAlloc (size_t sz) {
    size_t sz8 = (sz + 7) / 8;
    tBitSet *bits =  malloc (sizeof (tBitSet) + sz8);
    if (bits != NULL) {
        bits->sz = sz;
        for (size_t pos = 0; pos < sz8; pos++)
            bits->data[pos] = 0;
    }
    return bits;
}

void bitFree (tBitSet *bits) {
    free (bits);
}
```

Thirdly, the functions to set, clear, toggle and test a bit:

```
void bitSet (tBitSet *bits, size_t pos) {
    if (pos < bits->sz)
        bits->data[pos / 8] |= bitMask[pos % 8];
}

void bitClear (tBitSet *bits, size_t pos) {
    if (pos < bits->sz)
        bits->data[pos / 8] &= ~bitMask[pos % 8];
}

void bitToggle (tBitSet *bits, size_t pos) {
    if (pos < bits->sz)
        bits->data[pos / 8] ^= bitMask[pos % 8];
}

int bitTest (tBitSet *bits, size_t pos) {
    if (pos < bits->sz)
        return ((bits->data[pos / 8] & bitMask[pos % 8]) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    return 0;
}
```

And, finally of course, a test harness for checking that I haven't given you bogus code :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bitDump (char *desc, tBitSet *bits) {
    printf ("%s:", desc);
    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < (bits->sz + 7) / 8; pos++)
        printf (" $%02x", bits->data[pos]);
    putchar (':');
    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < bits->sz; pos++) {
        if ((pos % 8) == 0)
            putchar (' ');
        printf ("%d", bitTest (bits, pos));
    }
    for (size_t pos = bits->sz; (pos % 8) != 0; pos++)
        putchar ('_');
    putchar ('\n');
}

#define SZ 30

int main (void) {
    tBitSet *bits = bitAlloc (SZ);
    if (bits == NULL) {
        puts ("Could not allocate bitset");
        return 1;
    }

    bitDump ("Initial         ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < SZ; pos++) bitSet (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Set all         ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 1; pos < SZ; pos += 2) bitClear (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Clear every two ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < SZ; pos++) bitToggle (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Toggle all      ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 1; pos < SZ; pos += 2) bitClear (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Clear every two ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 4; pos < SZ; pos += 5) bitSet (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Set every five  ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < SZ; pos++) bitToggle (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Toggle all      ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < SZ; pos += 2) bitClear (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Clear odd       ", bits);

    for (size_t pos = 1; pos < SZ; pos += 2) bitClear (bits, pos);
    bitDump ("Clear even      ", bits);

    bitFree (bits);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output of that shows how it works:

```
Initial         : $00 $00 $00 $00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000__
Set all         : $ff $ff $ff $fc: 11111111 11111111 11111111 111111__
Clear every two : $aa $aa $aa $a8: 10101010 10101010 10101010 101010__
Toggle all      : $55 $55 $55 $54: 01010101 01010101 01010101 010101__
Clear every two : $00 $00 $00 $00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000__
Set every five  : $08 $42 $10 $84: 00001000 01000010 00010000 100001__
Toggle all      : $f7 $bd $ef $78: 11110111 10111101 11101111 011110__
Clear odd       : $55 $15 $45 $50: 01010101 00010101 01000101 010100__
Clear even      : $00 $00 $00 $00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000__
```

Comment: Excellent example. For the sake of completeness, you will probably want to add `#include <stdint.h>` for Linux (for `uint8_t`).